# Elimination left recursion for E := EE+|EE-|id

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, lexical-analysis

How to eliminate left recursion for the following grammar?

```
E := EE+|EE-|id
```

Using the common procedure:

```
A := Aa|b
```

translates to:

```
A := b|A'
A' := ϵ| Aa
```

Applying this to the original grammar we get:

```
A = E, a = (E+|E-) and b = id
```

Therefore:

```
E := id|E'
E' := ϵ|E(E+|E-)
```

But this grammar seems incorrect because

```
ϵE+ -> ϵ id +
```

would be valid
but that is an incorrect postfix expression.

Comment: You should perhaps mention that `e` is really `ϵ`. Fooled me, at any rate.

Comment: You've got a problem in your "translates to" definition: you've introduced an undefined term 'e'.  You can probably do something with regrouping the original as 'E := (EE(+|-))|id'.  Your final comment 'that is an incorrect postfix expression' is somewhat sweeping; why is 'e id +' incorrect?  It looks like 'push e; push id; evaluate +' which is usually OK.

Comment: @Konrad: ah - 'e' is empty?...that makes a difference.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to input epsilon. :)

Comment: @Absolute0: no problem - as long as you explain the notation you have used.

Comment: Shouldn't such questions be migrated to Theoretical Computer Science?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your “common procedure” is cited wrong. Taking it from the Dragon Book:

```
A := Aα | β
```

becomes

```
A  := βA′
A′ := αA′ | ϵ
```

… which yields:

```
E  := id E′
E′ := (E + | E -) E′ | ϵ
```

Comment: How do you input math symbols??

Comment: Absolute0: simple trick: I use a character table. I’m on OS X which has got a tool for that. On Windows, you can use `charmap.exe` which is hidden in the “Accessories” main menu (must be switched to Unicode, though).